# How to add an auto rotate function to my jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

i have a jquery accordion, and i want to add an auto-rotate function.
Demo of the slideshow : http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion.html

Comment: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/slideshow.html - that's the best I can do without seeing what code you are using, what you've tried or any kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

here is a demo : http://www.mediafire.com/?7k3eu7srwb8an9k